# R web scraping error message

Tags: r, web-scraping, statistics

Trying to scrape a web site for my PhD in statistics.

This is the part of the code I am interested in editing:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)                                              
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(datapasta)       
library(jsonlite)
library(countrycode)
library(httr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(XML)
library(curl)
library(countrycode)
library(httr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(dependency)
set_config(use_proxy(url="10.3.100.207",port=8080))
curl::nslookup("httpbin.org")
utils::nsl("httpbin.org")


## 12. Creating a function in order to scrape data from a website (in this case, FAO's)

   fao_get_news <- function(iso3) {

      GET(
      url = "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/",
      query = list(iso3=iso3)
      ) -> res

      warn_for_status(res)

      if (status_code(res) > 399) return(NULL)

      out <- content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8")
      out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(out)
      out$iso3 <- iso3

      tbl_df(out)

       }


## 13. Setting all the Country urls in order for them to be automatically scraped 
      pb <- progress_estimated(length(countrycode_data$iso3c[]))                             
      map_df(countrycode_data$iso3c[], ~{
      pb$tick()$print()
      Sys.sleep(5)
      fao_get_news(.x)
      }) -> xdf
```

I don't receive any negative feedback until point # 12.
The issues come up when I try to import single pages from the website I am interested in. 
Specifically, this is the error message I receive when I run # 13. :

```
Error during wrapup: Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds.
```

This is quite strange since the script (I have been advised by someone in some point of it: credit to "hrbrmstr" ) used to work until a week ago. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a reason to scrape Fao site?, because Fao has a free database...

Comment: Yes, the  reason is that the updates on single countries news would be easier to check out without going every time through all the pages. So I am trying to build up a dataset including all the links, title of the news etc.

Comment: The link you want to scrape is a blank page. But maybe you want to scrap the news section for each country, don't you?  http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/

Comment: Yes, srry. I had inserted the wrong link. I have updated it with the actual one into the script now. Thanks for noticing,

Comment: Yes, to avoid any confusion

Comment: The website seems really slow. Have you tried extending the timeout? Makes no sense to load packages twice. If there is an ordering preference due to masking, then remove the first instance of each of the duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to imcrease the timeout but haven't got any substantial result. 
I havem' t loaded twice then packages actually,  but just shown here everything im prder to make myself as clear as possible.

Comment: What Data are you trying to parse as JSON? I built a key table of all country pages and looped through... all return an html document... as expected./// what am I missing?

Comment: I am trying to parse the news. Specifically: titles, , dates, contents and keywords (the ones I choose, of course).